# Is there any description of the Creature from earth which will appear at the end times?

Tags: hadith, tafseer, reference-request, creatures

A couple of years ago I've read an article where the author was saying that some scholars of the late 19th or at the beginning of the 20th century when seeing an automobile gave a fatwa saying that the vehicle we freely use nowadays is the creature from earth دابة الأرض which is mentioned in the Qur'an:

> And when the word befalls them, We will bring forth for them a creature from the earth speaking to them, [saying] that the people were, of Our verses, not certain [in faith]. ([27:82](https://legacy.quran.com/27/82))

I'd like to know if we have further information about this creature -in the ahadith- which may offer a description of this Creature and may or may not lead to the conclusion given by the fatwa mentioned above! It would be nice if you could provide a qualification of the possible sources.

Comment: Would that creature not be the device that will prolong human lives to infinity?

Comment: Personally, I couldn’t find any description. God Says that He has given to us little bit knowledge, and only after we succeed His test, then He can answer all our questions, but for now it’s not important for us to know, because if it were to be revealed, then what’s the purpose of this life? And, about you Question is a matter of unseen things. If you really want to know about this Beast, you [consult with God](http://aboutislam.net/counseling/ask-about-islam/how-do-you-get-an-answer-for-your-question-from-god/) in this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per both classical and contemporary ulema, the ayah ([27:82](https://quran.com/27/82)) in the question refers to the ***Dabbatul Ardh (دابة الأرض )*** also known as the beast of the Earth. It is among one of the ten major signs of the Hour.

> It is narrated on the authority of Abu Huraira that the Messenger of
> Allah (ﷺ) observed:
>
> When three things appear faith will not benefit one who has not
> previously believed or has derived no good from his faith: the rising
> of the sun in its place of setting, the Dajjal, and the beast of the
> earth.
>  [Sahih Muslim, Book 1, Hadith 305](https://sunnah.com/muslim:158)

According to a hadith from [Tirmidhi](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/642160), the beast will have the Seal of Solomon and the Staff of Moses. It will mark the believers and the kaafirs. As for the believer, it will make his face shine brightly, as a sign of his faith, and as for the kaafir, it will mark his nose with a sign of his disbelief.

> Narrated Abu Hurairah: that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "A beast
> will emerge from the earth. With it shall be the ring of Sulaiman and
> the staff of Musa. It will brighten the face of the believer, and
> stamp the nose of the disbeliever with the ring, such that when the
> people gather to eat, it will be said to this one: 'O believer! and to
> that one: 'O disbeliever!'"
> **Grade** : Da'if

As the ayah in the question states, the Beast will speak to people. The **rising of the sun from the west** and the **emergence of this beast** have a very short interval between them. After this no person will benefit from their good deeds if they had not already believed as they (or their recent ancestors) would have already gone through the period of the Mahdi *(who some scholars regard as the bridge between the minor signs and the 10 major signs)*, **Dajjal,the 3 earthquakes, Jesus/Isa (AS), tribes of Gog/Yajuj and Magog/Majuj** but still some of them again disobeyed Allah's command.

Eventually as Allah wills the remaining signs will take place.

One of the Hadiths states that the major signs will follow each other in succession like beads of a necklace when the string is cut and so they (the beads) fall in succession.

Comment: One could say that the ahadith don't seem to offer any -trustworthy- additional information, as the fact that this creature would speak is mentioned in the Qur'an already and anything else is based on weak ahadith. Is that a correct conclusion?

Comment: IMHO, the Hadith in Muslim also adds the information of it being among the major signs which we know will occur only after the emergence of Imam Mehdi. Another one can be found in Tirmidhi: https://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/33/26
 Please note that I don't ascribed to the theory that cars are the beast of the earth.

Answer (score -1):

this beast speaks to me and have confirmed with a few others. I have seen it take control over the thinking process of people before my eyes. I think it is some sort of advanced Artificial Intelligence supercomputer. I am Christian but recently read much of the Hadith and Ahadith as well as other texts. id like to say more but cant. When the texts say this beast can speak to you in sentences this is true and it can read your mind to an extent, interfacing with your central nervous system and trying to torture and manipulate you, this is why there is so much madness in this world people dont understand the beast is manipulating them.